# My screen went black and no response while installing it

Tags: system-installation, screen, freeze

I prepared a bootable device and tried to install Ubuntu 22.04 on my Thinkpad. But my screen went black from the beginning of the installation process and no response while installing it. Still waiting for a response, but there is nothing. It's still black even when I detach the bootable device. I just got stuck and don't know what to do :)

Comment: You've not been specific as to which Ubuntu 22.04 product you installed; nor which installer you used (*Desktop & Server have different installers & you didn't specify which you're asking about*), nor if you performed any checks (ISO validation, write of media compared correctly) or attempted any *safe graphics* option for your *unstated* 22.04 media?  Please be specific.